# Find directory space on disk with powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem, disk-access

I wanted to know the size of my different sub-directories, so I followed the indications of [Getting Directory sizes powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/25/getting-directory-sizes-in-powershell.aspx) and [Display directory structure in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876279/display-directory-structure-with-size-in-powershell) and some others here in SO and somewhere else. Those functions work well, except I want to know the space that some *partially synced* folders occupy in disk (for example, I have a folder in Skydrive with only some of its sub-folders available online). When I call either function, they report the size of the folder *as if it were in disk*, not the actual disk usage. If I right-click the folder and check its properties, I can see clearly there is a difference between `size` and `size in disk`.

I have tried with `Sort-Object -Property Size` and `Sort-Object -Property Length` switches to either function (mostly based in the `Get-ChildItem` function), but both of them return size and not size in disk.

I guess there is a simple switch to make it take into account only actual disk usage, instead of total size, but I'm completely lost as to how to achieve it. Any leads are much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178919/powershell-get-diskusage-cmdlet-how-to-list-from-a-different-drive-directory

Comment: Please read this for "size in disk" info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959228/file-size-actual-number-of-bytes-used-on-disk-not-allocated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size On Disk is the actual size that your files occupy on the drive depending on the cluster size (or allocation unit), which most of the time is 4KB, but not all of the time. It depends on the file format and how it was formatted.

As long as the files are not compressed, it's a matter of finding out how many chunks of clusters are needed to fit each file. Keeping in mind that if a file is smaller than the cluster size, it will occupy one allocation unit.

If the file is compressed, the information is not easily available and needs to be retrieved via an API.

The following code is divided in 3 main sections:

1. It defines a Type used to access the function `GetCompressedFileSizeAPI` in kernel.dll. This function will retrieve the compressed size on disk of the file.
2. It uses WMI to determine the cluster size for the given `$path`
3. It computes the Size on Disk for the files in the folder and subfolders of `$path` depending if the file is compressed or not.

Note that the call to `Get-ChildItem` uses the `-force` switch to ensure we retrieve hidden and system files as well.

I'm not sure if this code will work with Skydrive, so you might need to change the WMI part.

```
$path = '.\'

Add-Type -TypeDefinition @" 
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class FileInfo 
{ 
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, EntryPoint="GetCompressedFileSize")]
    static extern uint GetCompressedFileSizeAPI(string lpFileName, out uint lpFileSizeHigh);

    public static ulong GetCompressedFileSize(string strFileName)
    {
        uint intHigh;
        uint intLow;
        intLow = GetCompressedFileSizeAPI(strFileName, out intHigh);
        int intError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (intHigh == 0 && intLow == 0xFFFFFFFF && intError != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(intError);
        else
            return ((ulong)intHigh << 32) + intLow;
    }
} 
"@


$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -force | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}

$drive = [string]$files[0].PSdrive+':'
$wql = "SELECT Blocksize FROM Win32_Volume where DriveLetter='$drive'"
$driveinfo = Get-WmiObject -Query $wql -ComputerName '.' 

$sizeondisk = ($files | %{      
    if ($_.Attributes -like "*compressed*")
    {

        if ($_.length -lt $driveinfo.BlockSize -and $_.length -ne 0)
        {
            $driveinfo.BlockSize
        }
        else
        {
            [FileInfo]::GetCompressedFileSize($_.fullname)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($_.length -lt $driveinfo.BlockSize -and $_.length -ne 0)
        {
            $driveinfo.BlockSize
        }
        else
        {
            ([math]::ceiling($_.length/$driveinfo.BlockSize))*$driveinfo.BlockSize
        }
    }
}|Measure -sum).sum

$sizeondisk
```

**UPDATE for Sparse Files:**

Let's see if this version works with sparse files, add this block of code at the end of the previous code, keep everything else the same:

```
$sparsesize = ($files | %{      
    if ($_.length -lt $driveinfo.BlockSize -and $_.length -ne 0)
    {
        $driveinfo.BlockSize
    }
    else
    {
        $_.fullname
        [FileInfo]::GetCompressedFileSize($_.fullname)
    }
}|Measure -sum).sum

$sparsesize
```

Sources:

[Understanding NTFS compression](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/05/20/understanding-ntfs-compression.aspx)

[Help querying files to return SIZE on DISK](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/cd98b6ec-5a8c-4edb-80ed-045aed2739d4/help-querying-files-to-return-size-on-disk?forum=ITCG)

[Size of compressed files (in French)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/fr-FR/fa8ecd1b-4a87-4281-b5be-5ffd91de9ee1/bizare-fsrm-quota-taille-fichier-vs-taille-occupe?forum=windowsserver8fr)

[How to get the actual size-on-disk of a file from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554010/how-to-get-the-actual-size-on-disk-of-a-file-from-powershell)

[Default cluster size for NTFS, FAT, and exFAT](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q140365)

Comment: Thanks for your interest and help. I ran your code, on a folder in my skydrive whose files I have set to "available online only". Its normal size is about 2.5 GB, and when I rightclick it, under properties it reports 1.4MB "on disk". Your code is accurately reporting back about 2.5 GB (very close to the code I referenced in the question), and does so even if I put the computer in plane-mode (files won't be availabe in that scenario). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Size is 2.5GB and Size on Disk is 1.4MB? Something is wrong, I wonder if it's using sparse files in which case this code won't be able to see it.

Comment: See this screenshot. It's in spanish, though. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lz0o1wp4nv2tuqj/size%20on%20disk.png?dl=0 I think the reason is most of the files are set to be "available online only" ??

Comment: Yes, looks like a sparse file, most of the non-meaningful data is not allocated on disk. In the following link they mention that `GetCompressedFileSize` can be used to determine the size. We use that for compressed code, so maybe you can force it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I updated the answer with a new block of code that should deal with the sparse files size.

Comment: It then throws an exception: (says System doesn't have access to file, which it certainly does) `Excepción al llamar a "GetCompressedFileSize" con los argumentos "1": "El sistema no tiene acceso al archivo"
En C:\Users\giova_000\Desktop\sizeod.ps1: 41 Carácter: 9
+         [FileInfo]::GetCompressedFileSize($_.fullname)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception`

Comment: It doesn't say which file though. It says that the script sizeod.ps1 at line 41 can't access `$_.fullname` would be good to output that filename so you can check if you have access to. I will update the code

Comment: @PavoDive: You're right - dropbox's function "only online" creates exactly those symptoms. "only online" is a feature which is not available for dropbox basic-accounts (there are a few exceptions), i. e. it depends on your "plan" / contract. So far I didn't find a solution using powershell. I think the only way I'm counting for is the dropbox API (and therefore at the end of the day "If the file is compressed, the information is not easily available and needs to be retrieved via an API." is right).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I was encountering errors in regards to certain values being strings and not numeric in the sparse file code snippet.

However, I noticed when I took out the " $_.fullname" from below

```
$sparsesize = ($files | %{      
if ($_.length -lt $driveinfo.BlockSize -and $_.length -ne 0)
{
    $driveinfo.BlockSize
}
else
{
    $_.fullname
    [FileInfo]::GetCompressedFileSize($_.fullname)
}
}|Measure -sum).sum

$sparsesize
```

and change it to

```
$sparsesize = ($files | %{      
if ($_.length -lt $driveinfo.BlockSize -and $_.length -ne 0)
{
    $driveinfo.BlockSize
}
else
{
    [FileInfo]::GetCompressedFileSize($_.fullname)
}
}|Measure -sum).sum

$sparsesize
```

Then it returned a numeric value.